# Finding the actual query which causing issue inside a function or procedure present in pg_stat_activity

Tags: postgresql, session

I have run pg_stat_activity I found there are log of session running. One of session using a function. In that function there are several blocks or dml select operations are being performed. How can I find the select or dml operation causing issue. Because directly it is not available in the query section of pg_stat_activity. Please help. Thank you.

I have tried to find out solution but unable to get. As in Oracle it is readily available in v$ession even any procedure is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the slow statement with `pg_stat_statements` (if you enable the extension and set `pg_stat_statements.track = all`), or you can log the slow statement with [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) (which I recommend).

In `postgresql.conf`, set

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain'

auto_explain.log_min_duration = 1000  # if you want to catch anything slower than a second
auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on
```

Then restart PostgreSQL.

Answer (score -1):

Enable query logging in your PostgreSQL setup by setting `log_statement = 'all'` to identify the specific SQL statement that is creating problems with a PostgreSQL function. Next, use the `pg_stat_activity` command to locate the session that is now running the function, note its backend PID, and look for items pertaining to that PID in the PostgreSQL log files. Consider the scenario where you are tracking a function called `my_function()` in a session with a PID of 12345. You may discover:

```
2023-09-28 14:32:45.123 EDT [12345] [mydatabase] [myuser] [myapp] LOG:  statement: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE condition = 'something';
2023-09-28 14:34:12.456 EDT [12345] [mydatabase] [myuser] [myapp] LOG:  statement: UPDATE my_table SET column = 'new_value' WHERE condition = 'something_else';
```

You may identify and examine the issue SQL statements that were performed within the function by looking at the log entries connected to the PID of the session.

Hope this helps, do let me know if this helps.

Comment: That will only show the function call.